# Check for a pattern (that has double values) to match. Regex

Tags: java, regex

I have two strings:

1. First string should match this pattern: "anyDoubleValue anyDoubleValue anyDoubleValue". Please note these double values are separated by white spaces. What I mean by anyDoubleValue is: any integer or decimal value.
2. Second string should match this pattern: "aSet aSet aSet". The set "aSet" should only have -1 or 0 or 1. Also note that these sets are separated by white spaces.

I have tried the following, but they doesn't serve the purpose:

```
if(aString.matches("[\\d\\s\\d\\s\\d]"){//do foo}
if(anotherString.matches("[0-1\\s0-1\\s0-1]")){// do bar}
```

Comment: Can you define "DoubleValue"?

Comment: Your question is poorly worded. Instead of providing placeholders, provide sample strings, so there isn't so much ambiguity about what you're asking. Right now, it looks like you're trying to match the literal string "anyDoubleValue" multiple times, but your narrative suggests you're actually trying to match a `double` value.

Comment: what I mean by anyDoubleValue is: any integer or any decimal value.

Comment: @Palpatim. Okay I will try to improve the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For first one:**

Pattern to match a double value would be - `"-?\\d+(.\\d+)?"`. Ok, this is a very general one. Doesn't consider scientific notation.

So, to get your sequence of double value and whitespace, use:

```
// Removed non-captured group for readability purpose
(-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?)(?:\\s(-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?)){2}
```

**For second one:**

```
(?:0|-?1)(\\s(?:0|-?1)){2}
```

Comment: I tried to match with a string that has white space at the beginning and/or at the end. Can you tell why it doesn't match? Please see this:

(-?\s\d+(\.\d+)?)\s(-?\d+(\.\d+)?)\s(-?\d+(\.\d+\s)?), 
(-?\d+(\.\d+)?)\s(-?\d+(\.\d+)?)\s(-?\d+(\.\d+\s)?),
(-?\s\d+(\.\d+)?)\s(-?\d+(\.\d+)?)\s(-?\d+(\.\d+)?).

Answer (score 1):

For the first matching:

```
^(\d+(\.\d+)?)\s(\d+(\.\d+)?)\s(\d+(\.\d+)?)$
```

Note that it allows double values with or without their decimal portion

[Check on Regex 101](http://regex101.com/r/kH4fK9)

For the second matching:

```
^(\-1|0|1)\s(\-1|0|1)\s(\-1|0|1)$
```

[Check on Regex 101](http://regex101.com/r/gB7yR3)

Answer (score 0):

For the first:

```
"-?[0-9](?:\\.[0-9]+)? -?[0-9](?:\\.[0-9]+)? -?[0-9](?:\\.[0-9]+)?"
```

For the second:

```
"(?:0|-?1) (?:0|-?1) (?:0|-?1)"
```